# XSL template processes all descendants, not just children

Tags: xslt

Given the following XML and XSL transformation, I'd expect two `<node/>` elements in the output containing the texts `first` and `second`. This expectation is based on the following reasoning:

1. The template with `match="/root"` will execute first. The `<xsl:apply-templates/>` instruction in this template will apply the most specific templates [for all child nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules).
2. These `<foo/>` child nodes will be processed by the second template. This template also contains the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` instruction, which applies templates to the child nodes of these nodes.
3. The `<foo/>` nodes only contain `<bar/>` nodes, which don't match any template. This implies that no further nodes will be processed.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<root>
  <foo name="first">
    <bar>
      <foo name="nested"/>
    </bar>
  </foo>
  <foo name="second">
    <bar>
      <baz>
        <foo name="nested"/>
      </baz>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <node>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </node>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the actual result of the above transformation contains four `<node/>` elements, of which two contain the text `nested`. This means that the second template is also applied to the most inner `<foo/>` nodes. But according to the aforementioned step 3, the processing engine should never reach these nodes.

I have tested the transformation in multiple web browsers and using the Notepad++ XML Tools plug-in, and all of them show the "wrong" result. So I guess I'm wrong here, but **what's wrong with my reasoning?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the bar nodes do match a template, they match the built in "*" template, which propagates the templates, calling the inner bar/node template

Comment: You're right, I wasn't aware of the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is that template matching is done according to nesting levels. This is not the case.

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
```

This matches *all* `foo` elements, whatever their nesting level, so when calling `apply-templates`, all `foo` elements will use this template.

The [built in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) will also cause the `bar` nodes to be matched.

Comment: Yes, the template will match all `<foo/>` elements, regardless of nesting levels. But `apply-templates` *does* take nesting level into account. So without mentioning the built-in template, your answer is slightly inaccurate.